# Which colourful insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found it on my plant this morning while watering it. Location: Hyderabad, Telangana, India. Any ideas?

[image: the photo of the insect]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice find! That most definitely is a [Poekilocerus pictus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poekilocerus_pictus), also known as a "Painted Grasshopper".

[image]

[image]